# From an Azure ARM template DSC extension, a module fails to import because running scripts is disabled on this system

Tags: azure, dsc, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to create a Windows 10 VM in Azure from an ARM template and configure it with a DSC extension to change the letter of the temporary drive.

I found the module cMoveAzureTempDrive that allow to do it easily.
However when I deploy the template in Azure I receive an error saying that the module cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on the system :

```
{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"VMExtensionProvisioningError","message":"VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'Install'. Error message: \"DSC Configuration 'Install' completed with error(s). Following are the first few: Importing module cMoveAzureTempDrive failed with error - File C:\\Program Files\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules\\cMoveAzureTempDrive\\cMoveAzureTempDrive.psm1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.\"\r\n\r\nMore information on troubleshooting is available at https://aka.ms/VMExtensionDSCWindowsTroubleshoot "}]}
```

I understand that I could enable script execution from a custom script extension but it doesn't seem optimal to me that we can't use DSC module without doing that. I have the same problem with all external modules.

Do you have a solution to be able to use DSC modules?

Here is my DSC extension in the ARM template :

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
    "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('vmName'),'/', 'Install')]",
    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
    "tags": "[parameters('resourceTags')]",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/',parameters('vmName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
        "type": "DSC",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "2.9",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion":true,
        "settings": {
            "wmfVersion": "latest",
            "configuration": {
                "url": "[variables('DSCLocationURI')]",
                "script": "Install.ps1",
                "function": "Install"
            },
            "configurationArguments": {
            }
        },
        "protectedSettings": {
            "configurationUrlSasToken": "[parameters('storageAccountSASToken')]"
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my DSC code :

```
{
   
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName 'PSDesiredStateConfiguration'
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName 'cAzureStorage'
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName 'cMoveAzureTempDrive'

    Node localhost
    {
        LocalConfigurationManager
        {
            ActionAfterReboot = 'ContinueConfiguration'
            RebootNodeIfNeeded = $true
        }

        cMoveAzureTempDrive cMoveAzureTempDrive
        {
            TempDriveLetter = 'T'
            Name = "MachineName"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error seems to come from the fact that Win10 has default Executionpolicy Restricted, hence the DSC is denied to run.
If you change the Executionpolicy on the client from Restricted to Remotesigned, the problem disappears.

You could also change the ExecutionPolicy in the DSC script. There is example of the script:

```
Configuration Security_Baseline_Windows_Client
{
  Import-DSCResource -ModuleName 'SecurityPolicyDSC'            # SecurityPolicyDSC is a Powershell Module for Security Settings  

  Import-DSCResource -ModuleName 'AuditPolicyDsc'               # AuditPolicyDsc is a Powershell Module for Advanced Audit Settings 

  Import-DscResource -ModuleName 'NetworkingDsc'                # NetworkingDsc is a Powershell Module for Firewall Settings 

  Import-DscResource -ModuleName 'PSDesiredStateConfiguration'  # PSDesiredStateConfiguration is a module that contains cmdlets that designed to work with DSC Resources.
  Node localhost
  {
    Script ExecutionPolicy
    {
        SetScript = {
            Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force
        }
        TestScript = { $false }
        GetScript  = { @{} }
    }
```

This setting causes the Powershell extension to fail.
However, it is recommended by MS Security baseline to keep this setting.